# Why are copper tracks orange-gold?

Tags: pcb, copper

I have in front of me a raw PCB. The surface mostly has three colors: dark green, orange-gold and white.

As I understand, the green is resist, the orange-gold is copper, and the white just the silk screen.

I find it surprising the color of the PCB's surface copper is quite different to the color of copper pipes. Please compare the orange-gold of PCBs, and the reddish-orange of copper pipes.

Why does PCB copper look more yellow than copper pipes?

[image]
[image]

Comment: +1 Nice question & answer by Brian. A while ago (not ordering many PCBs directly) I commented to a colleague I'd got 'free' gold plating from a PCB manufactuer I hadn't used before and he convinced me I was colour blind and it was just copper.

Comment: All that glitters is not copper, you know! What you have here is "fool's copper". :)

Comment: You may look at [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printed_circuit_board#Exposed_conductor_plating_and_coating) for more information.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Because that board has been gold plated. Ironically, that saves money; copper tarnishes, and would need expensive cleaning immediately before soldering. And gold on the contact fingers makes for reliable connections. Other platings are possible : tin or silver, and formerly lead-based solder. Scrape some green solder-resist off the earth track and you would see a more reddish metal, though it would take a few months to tarnish to the colour of those pipes.

EDIT : the gold plating on the contact fingers may be a different process (thicker plating, to resist wear) - plating on the board itself will be VERY thin.

Comment: The mystery of [skin depth article on micrwoaves101](http://www.microwaves101.com/encyclopedia/skindepth.cfm) is a very interesting point of what some thing the gold plating can help with. The section **The mystery of skin depth - a timeless story** is the specific section to read and leads to some entertainment.

Comment: really convincing answer to a good question...

Answer (score 18):

Just for sake of complete information, even if you scrape off the resist to get to the real copper underneath, it will still be pretty goldish. Pure clean copper is a very nice goldish color. The Pipes you see at the store are already in a state of oxidation, giving it the rustier color. Eventually those unsealed pipes will turn a green color.

[image: Copper Oxidation Guide]

Essentially, the same thing that happened to the Statue of Liberty. It wasn't meant to be green. Copper Tarnishes, oxidizes, into a Patina. Iron oxidizes into Rust. Aluminum tarnishes, oxidizes into Aluminum Oxide, which seals the Aluminum, and gives it a duller shine. Silver does as well. Raw Gold is not shiny.

Comment: IME fresh copper is pink, old dry copper (e.g. pipes that did not leak) is brown and old damp copper (either outdoors or where a pipe has leaked) gives the green color. Gold OTOH is yellow which is pretty distinct from copper of any age.

Comment: @passerby why not blue (cu2+)?

Comment: My father lived in a big old house in Vermont with a copper roof. At one point he had to have it replaced. Apparently, the day after it was done the daughter of a neighbor got off the school bus, then rushed home, saying, "Mother! Mother! The Beasts have gold roof!"

Answer (score 1):

Unless you specified a gold plating technology, that board is probably OSP: organic solderability protector a.k.a. "organic solder mask", "copper protector" or "preflux".

It's been coated with thin transparent protective layers (often containing some dissolved copper).  It's not just a coating: it reacts with the copper substrate to form a locked surface, preventing oxidation. Unlike tin/lead/paladium/gold surface treatments, the organic compound is removed by flux when soldering.